# What is the equivalent of synchronized( object ) in Reentrant lock in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, reentrantlock

In the code given below. How can I know which object Reentrant Lock has locked ?

```
Public class Test {

    Map obj1 = new HashMap();
    Object ob2 = new Object();

    void Method() {

        //First
        synchronized(ob1) { // Locks obj1

        }
        synchronized(ob2) { // Locks obj2

        }

        //Second
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(); // Which object is getting locked here? 
        lock.lock();
        try {

        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }

}
```

In the above example which Object is getting locked ? If I want to explicitly lock obj1 and obj2 using Reentrant lock how is it possible ?

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: `ReentrantLock` hasn't locked any object. It **is** a lock.

Comment: @Michael  - I did not understand your last comment. Can you tell me in the second part which object is locked

Comment: Objects contain a thing called an implicit monitor lock. When you synchronize on an object, imagine you're making a method call which manipulates a magic hidden field inside the object. This hidden field, the monitor lock, is responsible for saying whether the object is locked or not. Think of it like a boolean flag. It doesn't physically change anything, but all other synchronized blocks know about it and respect it. An explicit lock like a reentrant lock is the same, but it is not private to an object, nor is it explicitly associated with any.

Comment: @Michael - Thanks for answering. So I suppose in the above example if I want to explicitly lock obj1 and obj2 using Reentrant that will not be possible

Comment: The key word "explicitly". No, you can't explicitly do that. One of the problems with explicit locks is that its sometimes not clear what objects they're intended to be locking. There are [some annotations](https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/GuardedBy) which you can use to make the intent clearer, and even throw compile-time errors if they're not used correctly, but these are supplementary. Annotations are certainly not required to use an explicit lock

Comment: @Michael: I actually think the problem is the other way around: using the objects themselves as the monitor implies that locking them somehow "locks the object" (as in, makes concurrent access impossible), which it does not do. It only helps when all other code also respects the "lock first, then access" pattern, which is made much more explicit if you use an explicit Lock object.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(); // Which object is getting locked here? 
> lock.lock();
> ```

The `lock` object is getting locked there.

I think maybe you misunderstand what `synchronized(ob1) {...}` does. It does *not* prevent other threads from using `obj1`. The only thing it prevents is, it prevents other threads from being synchronized on the same object at the same time.

Locks in Java (and in most other programming languages/libraries) are so-called [*advisory locks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)). "Advisory" means, the programmer has to know what data are supposed to be protected by the lock, and the programmer is responsible for ensuring that no thread in the program ever uses that data except when the thread has locked the lock.

---

FYI: A "clean" practice in Java is to use `synchronized` in this way:

```
class MyClass {

    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private TypeA sharedMemberVariable_a;
    private TypeB sharedMemberVariable_b;
    ...

    public SomeType someMethod() {
        ...
        synchronized(lock) {
            ...access shared member variables...
        }
        return ...;
    }
}
```

This pattern allows you to publish instances of `MyClass` without exposing the `lock` object to callers.  It also makes very clear the distinction between the `lock` object itself, and the data/relationships that are protected by the lock.

The pattern also makes it trivially easy to switch from using `synchronized` to using a `Lock` object if you need to do so in the future.

Comment: @Michael, Yes. Apparently so. Edits applied. Thanks.