# Understanding locks usage in Java

Tags: java, synchronization, locks

I'm trying to understand the difference between synchronized and locks in Java and I found this other question that I still don't understand fully:
[What is the equivalent of synchronized( object ) in Reentrant lock in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64103796/12375196)

In particular I don't understand why the lock.lock() has been written outside the try block.

From what I understood locks are used inside method bodies and the lock.lock() is written as the first thing inside a try block to make sure that only one thread at a time can execute what's inside that try block, until the lock is unlocked with the lock.unlock() call, that is written in a finally block after the try block.

But if lock.lock() is invoked outside of a method body and outside of a block, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The try-finally construction is there to guarantee that the lock will be released.

The reason why 'lock' is writen before 'try' is that, until locking is complete, there's nothing to unlock - so it's a bug to have a finally clause that unconditionally unlocks something that may not have been locked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand now why it has to be written just before try block. And what about a lock.lock() call written outside a method body? is there a situation where it makes sense?

Comment: The only place you can execute code outside a method body is in constructors or equivalently in initializers.  There may be some use-case for doing that, but it's not common, I can't come up with anything off the top of my head,, and in any case the next questions would be "what is the scope of the lock?" and "where is the unlock?".